std::setprecision with small number
The following code is compiled using VS2022
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double d1 = 0.0006;
    double d2 = 0.00006;
    double d3 = 1.0006;
    double d4 = 1.00006;

    std::cout << "d1=" << std::setprecision(9) << d1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "d2=" << std::setprecision(9) << d2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "d3=" << std::setprecision(9) << d3 << "\n";
    std::cout << "d4=" << std::setprecision(9) << d4 << "\n";
        
    return 0;
}

Output is
d1=0.0006
d2=6e-05
d3=1.0006
d4=1.00006

I am trying to understand how std::setprecision works (without using std::fixed).
Why is d2 outputted using scientific format even though I specified ample precision?
Why is d2 and d4 outputting using different format? Is there special handling of very small numbers?

d2 has leading zeros which are not significant.  That makes it a viable candidate to be expressed in scientific format.  d4 has a leading 1 in the units place, making all the zeros significant zeros.

d1 also has leading zeros but I am guessing they are considered significant? Is there a hardcoded cut-off limit? Is this specified in C++ standard or compiler dependent?

d1 also has leading zeros but I am guessing they are considered significant?  No, they are also insignificant zeros.  There is probably a hardcoded cut-off limit.  I do not know if the cut-off limit is specified in the C++ standard or if it is compiler dependent.

by default the conversion is equivalent to printf("%g") https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf


Why is d2 outputted using scientific format even though I specified ample precision?

By default https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put uses %g as in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf .

Let P equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is not specified, or 1 if the precision is ​0​. Then, if a conversion with style E would have an exponent of X:

if P > X ≥ −4, the conversion is with style f or F and precision P − 1 − X.
otherwise, the conversion is with style e or E and precision P − 1.


The precision is P=9. The number is 6e-5, so exponent is X=-5. P > X ≥ −4 is false, because exponent -5 is lower than -4. So the conversion is done with %e, which prints in "e"xponent notation.

Why is d2 and d4 outputting using different format?

See the rule above, the exponents of numbers is between 9 and -4.

Is there special handling of very small numbers?

Generally, yes - the e-4 is the "cutoff".

If not using std::fixed or std::scientific then printing a float is equivalent to printf("%g", value):

Converts floating-point number to decimal or decimal exponent notation depending on the value and the precision. 

For the g conversion style conversion with style e or f will be performed.
Let P equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is not specified, or 1 if the precision is ​0​. Then, if a conversion with style E would have an exponent of X:

if P > X ≥ −4, the conversion is with style f or F and precision P − 1 − X.
otherwise, the conversion is with style e or E and precision P − 1.


So if a number has 4 or more leading zeros after the decimal point then it'll be formatted using the scientific format regardless of the precision.
If you want control over how the numbers are formatted use std::fixed or std::scientific.
